# Incremental changes to Ember Data many-to-many relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my web application, I have products and shopping lists. The server provides REST endpoints.

```
GET /api/shopping-lists/abc
```

returns

```
{
  shoppingList: {
    id: "abc",
    products: ["p123", "p234", "p345"]
  }
}
```

In my `Ember 1.7.0` application, I use `Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.6`. My models look like this:

```
App.ShoppingList = DS.Model.extend({
    products: DS.hasMany("product", {async: true}),
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name:  DS.attr("string")
});
```

As I couldn't find canonical information on the right "Ember way" of adding and removing records from a many-to-many relationship, I am adding and removing products to/from a shopping list like this:

```
function addToShoppingList(shoppingList, toBeAddedProduct) {

    shoppingList.get("products").then( function(products) {
        products.pushObject( toBeAddedProduct );
        shoppingList.save();
    });

}


function removeFromShoppingList(shoppingList, toBeRemovedProduct) {

    shoppingList.get("products").then( function(products) {
        products.removeObject( toBeRemovedProduct );
        shoppingList.save();
    });

}
```

At the moment above functions call `shoppingList.save()`, Ember Data will send a `PUT` request with a JSON payload that includes IDs of **all** products on this shopping list:

```
addToShoppingList(abcShoppingList, p456Product);

//results in PUT on /api/shopping-lists/abc with payload:
{
    "shoppingList" : {
        "products" : ["p123", "p234", "p345", "p456"]
    }
}
```

As shopping lists can become long, I'd rather prefer to have only an **incremental** update that only includes the changes of shopping list, i.e.:

```
{
    "shoppingList" : {
        "products" : ["p456"]
    }
}
```

Can I make Ember Data to only `PUT` the changes to a records, instead of sending the full record?

Also, the `removeFromShoppingList(..)` function will send the full record as a **`PUT`** request. Instead, I would prefer to have it send an **incremental `DELETE`** request.

Comment: No, you can't.  Is that the only time you'd be saving the shoppingList model?

Comment: @Kingpin2k, `addToShoppingList(..)` and `removeFromShoppingList(..)` are currently the only places in my code that will modify a `ShoppingList`'s `products` relationship. I have been thinking about to take care of doing the custom requests and record updates myself without relying on Ember Data, but I would have guessed that Ember Data comes with such functionality out of the box...

Comment: Just manually handle it, it'll be easier.  I don't know of any other client side ORM that does incremental updates like what you're talking about.

Comment: Not sure why my answer was downvoted, a reason would be basic courtesy given the amount of consideration put into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ember Data allows you to implement whatever you need to build a json payload in the appropriate model serializer and also in the adapter if need be. I suggest looking at the Ember Data source code for JSONSerializer and RESTSerializer as there is a huge amount of flexibility for tuning the JSON both produced(serialize) and consumed(normalize).

It sounds like you want to implement PATCH semantics but you can do what you want with PUT providing your URL endpoint targets just the products relationship, eg `/api/shopping-lists/123/products`. This is different to targeting the full model `/api/shopping-lists/123` and PUTing just the "products" array as that is NOT conforming to HTTP semantics.

A URL identifies a resource and a GET and PUT or DELETE on that endpoint can idempotently update or remove just a single attribute or even a subset of a value so long as the URL scopes to that attribute or some subset, it is by definition a distinct resource and HTTP fully supports overlapping resources and even multiple resources being affected by a PUT.

So taking this further you may represent the products in a shopping list as separate resources: `/api/shopping-lists/123/:product-id` and just use DELETE to remove and PUT to create/add a product to the list. Many URL designs are possible including nested urls as shown or ones thst use a composite key or even a surrogate key, so you will have to consider what works best on your server.

You may decide to implement an Ember Data join model eg `ShoppingListProduct` to make this easier to manage. ShoppingListProduct will then specify `belongsTo` relationships for ShoppingList and Product. You can also manufacture the 'id' attribute from both belongsTo relationships so the DS Store identity map works as expected. This is trivial to implement in your model serializer.

**UPDATE**

To answer your comment below a good rule to follow is to think of PUT as REPLACE rather than UPDATE, so that what you PUT is what you should GET back assuming nothing else has modified the resource since your PUT. If that's not true it could be an indication you haven't defined a fine enough granularity on your URLs to scope what you are replacing, or you perhaps should consider using PATCH to target just the attributes you want to change.

I dont know if there is "best practice " per se but I tend to only update resources from the endpoint that has the foreign key (ie the belongsTo side). Many to many relationships I usually end up with a join resource eg Taggings or Friendship so its just managing relationships via belongsTo again. This tends to follow what you do in a relational database so it works well.

Comment: Great answer. I was wondering what is/are the correct RESTful way(s) of adding and removing *relationships* between resources. `PATCH` seems to add an additional way... P.S.: why is `PUT`ting a `products`-rooted JSON payload on `/api/shopping-lists/123` discouraged?

Comment: Updated answer to provide some guidance on managing relationships and REST/PUT